# NSMutableArray with int values from 1 to 100

Tags: ios, objective-c

This should be dead easy, but somehow it doesn't want to work for me. Using iOS 7 and XCode 5.
All I'm trying to do is create an array with values from 1 to 100.

```
NSMutableArray *array;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    [array addObject:i];
}
```

This doesn't work. I get a "Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC.
I get it, I can't add primitive types to an NSMutableArray.

```
    [array addObject:@i];
```

This doesn't work either. I get a "unexpected '@' in program"

```
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
```

(either case) This "works" (compiles) but it really doesn't "work". The problem with this is that the value from NSNumber is really not a 1-100. What I get for each row is "147212864", 147212832", "147212840"...not what I want.

Lastly:

```
for (NSNumber *i = 0; i < [NSNumber numberWithInteger:100]; i++)
{
    [array addObject:i];
}
```

This also doesn't compile. I get an error on the i++. "Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'NSNumber', which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform"

Any suggestions on how to do this extremely simple thing on obj-c?

Comment: Minimally, `@i` should be `@(i)`

Comment: And don't forget that on the other end you need to do `intValue` on the NSNumber to get the `int` back.

Comment: Oh crap, I forgot to mention that way.

This doesn't add anything to my array:

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        [array addObject:@(i) ];
    }
    NSLog(@"count in fillUp = %d", [array count]);
This returns a count of 0

Comment: How are you validating what's in your array? How are you printing it out?

Comment: @TooManyEduardos. That's because you forgot to allocate and init your array.

Comment: it should actually be `[array addObject:@(i + 1)];` for numbers 1 through 100.

Comment: sorry, the parentheses works. I was missing the allow as well after all my re-writing.

Comment: Or loop from 1 to `<=` 100, etc.

Comment: When you are getting the "147212864", 147212832", "147212840" it is because you are outputing the values wrongly. It is obvious those are pointer values, not the value stored in objects at those locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves, I think you're simply missing parenthesis around the `NSNumber` shorthand expression.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    [array addObject:@(i)];
}
```

Comment: This can't work unless you allocate and init the array first. `NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array]`

Comment: @ahwulf Absolutely correct. I took the code posted in the question and only focused on the issue with the `NSNumber` literal. I'll edit for your concerns for any future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Either one of these should work:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    [array addObject:@(i)];
}
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```

Here are the reasons why your code snippets did not work:

1. `[array addObject:i]` - You cannot add primitives to Cocoa collections
2. `[array addObject:@i]` - You forgot to enclose the expression `i` in parentheses
3. `NSNumber *i = 0; i < [NSNumber numberWithInteger:100]; i++` - You cannot increment `NSNumber` without "unwrapping" its value first.

Comment: damn parentheses.
Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Minimally, `@i` should be `@(i)` as described [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#boxed-expressions). You are also forgetting to allocate and initialise your array

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    [array addObject:@(i)];
}
```

And since you are getting: `"147212864", 147212832", "147212840"...not what I want.`, I think you are probably printing out your information wrongly or because the array is unallocated, that's simply garbage. Can you show us how you are outputting?

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSNumber *myNum;
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

     myNum = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:i];
     [array addObject:myNum];
 }
 NSLog(@"%@", array); // 1 - 99 as expected
```

Worked for me :)

Comment: "1 - 99 as expected". Well, I'd expect 0 through 99 (from you code).

Comment: my childhood is a lie

Answer (score -1):

Just saying: Turn on all reasonable warnings in your Xcode project. Then read what the warnings are saying and do something about them. When you write something like

```
for (NSNumber *i = 0; i < [NSNumber numberWithInteger:100]; i++)
```

What does a for loop do? An object is in the end a pointer. So you initalise i to nil. Then you compare a pointer with a random pointer: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:100] returns a pointer to an object which could be anywhere in memory, and you compare pointers. Next the i++: No, you can't increment a pointer to an NSNumber. It doesn't make sense.